# Git Command line list only directories without files

Tags: git, github

I have a bunch of folders and files within a Git repo. I want to just list the directories and not the files.

Currently if I do

`git ls-files --directory`

It gives the following result

```
src/main/java/com/ttg/ewq/servicetemp/ReleaseOrder_Service.java
src/main/java/com/ttg/ewq/servicetemp/ReleaseOrder_Test.java
src/main/java/com/ttg/ewq/servicetemp/Shipment_servicetemp_Service.java
src/main/java/com/ttg/ewq/servicetemp/Shipment_servicetemp_Service_test.java
src/main/java/com/ttg/ewq/servicetemp/DepositeService_Service.java
src/main/java/com/ttg/ewq/servicetemp/DepositeService_Test.java
src/main/java/com/ttg/ewq/servicetemp/servicetemp_Service.java
src/main/java/com/ttg/ewq/servicetemp/sservicetemp_Test.java
```

I don't want to see the java files and other text files inside the folders. I just need the folder names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. It's

`git ls-tree -d -r master --name-only`